# Performing a Shift Register operation on an array in TwinCAT3 using SHL/SHR

Tags: plc, twincat, codesys, iec61131-3

I am very new to PLC programming. Can anyone help with explaining how I can perform a SHR/SHL operation on an array of INT of lets say 10 elements using TwinCAT3. They way I thought I would do this is by moving the shift register one place so that Element 0 becomes Element 1, Element 1 becomes Element 2 ..etc. and the last Element is lost.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The `SHL` and `SHR` operators work not on arrays, but on individual registers, e.g. `SHL(3, 1)` will result in 6 (`0000 0011` -> `0000 0110`). However If you shift a number beyond it's holding capacity, the bits that go past the boundary are completely lost, i.e. they do *NOT* overflow into the next memory register!

Comment: Thank you for your reply Guiorgy. Is there any method I can use to shift the elements in an array to the left or right. Also for the example you stated above, if I want to perform a loop operation where the values returns to its original after 8 shifts, how do I do that. I am not very familiar with the "Memory Move" operation which could be a possibility.

Comment: Just as a point of clarification, What operations do you want to perform on the actual data? An array may not be the ideal structure for your use case

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you are working with:

```
VAR
  aiElements : ARRAY[0..uiElementsCount-1] OF INT;
  i : INT;
END_VAR

VAR CONSTANT
  uiElementsCount : INT := 10;
END_VAR
```

To move each value one index forward (0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, etc.) you can do the following:

```
FOR i := uiElementsCount-1 TO 1 BY -1 DO
  aiElements[i] := aiElements[i-1];
END_FOR
```

To move each value one index backward (1 -> 0, 2 -> 1, etc.):

```
FOR i := 0 TO uiElementsCount-2 DO
  aiElements[i] := aiElements[i+1];
END_FOR
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jacek. 

I want to setup an INT array for the shift register, say 10 elements and put a 1 in element 0 so that I can check to see if it works. They way I thought I would do this is by moving the shift register one place so that Element 0 becomes Element 1, Element 1 becomes Element 2 ..etc. and the last Element is lost. 

Also, how do I use the TC3 System Timers to calculate the time required to perform the complete shift (9 operations).

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I've updated my answer. Please, update the question itself, so it's easier for future readers. As for calculating time - it deserves separate question.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it only shifts the bitstream of the elements itself, it doesn't move the element to the next location on the array, which is what I was hoping to achieve, if possible.

Comment: @pro_to_be What do you mean by "this shifts bitstream of the elements"? There's no shifting going on here, this example just moves every element to the left(/right) by one, which seems to be what you were asking for. If this isn't it, maybe give a more concrete example of the data you have and the data you want to get after the transformation in your question please